# Minified React error #321 on using useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm having trouble with "Minified React error #321". I only get it when i'm using useEffect. Hopefully someone can help me out, i've been stuck for 3 hours trying to figure something out.

I'm beginning by exporting a .js file (not sure if js/jsx matters)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";

export default function CalDisplayLogic() {

setOccupiedFinalArray(occupiedBy); //occupiedBy is an array.

return occupiedFinalArray;
}
```

[Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Yv4.png)

I don't seem to get this error whenever i remove useEffect, but the component constantly re-renders if i don't. Am wondering if there is any other solution for this.

```
import CalDisplayLogic from "./CalDisplayLogic";
export default function CalendarDisplay() {
useEffect(() => {
    CalDisplayLogic();
    console.log("effectRunning");
  }, [selectedDateState]);
```

Comment: Why didn't you follow the link in the error? `CalDisplayLogic` is a hook, hooks can't be called inside `useEffect`

Comment: it's not very clear from the code what's going on. f.ex. "selectedDateState" is not in props ,so where is it coming from? since it's the only dependency, that's probably the reason it re-renders. And, yes, follow that link to see the full message